# fractional second is not being saved in database even though the column type is datetime(6)?

Tags: java, mysql, grails

I am converting the racestarttime and raceendtime which are epoch time to date as follows.

```
  Date startDateTime = new Date(raceStartTime.toLong())
  Date endDateTime = new Date(raceEndTime.toLong())
```

The first two columns are start and end date time and the last two columns are epoch millisecond start and end time. The date columns in mysql are of type datetime(6).Why is the fractional part not saved in database? I appreciate any insights. I am using grails 2.2 and mysql 5.7.

[image]

Comment: What is `Date`? `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? Anyway, you should be using `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: What type does `raceStartTime` have?

Comment: *Why is the fractional part not saved in database?* Are you sure that it exists in a value which you save?